# Got an error while using Sencha touch 2.1.1 CDN

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I've built my app using sencha touch 2.0 CDN and now I am trying to migrate to 2.1.1. But, I am getting an error - *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )* in sencha-touch-all.js:21.

CDN URL is: http://cdn.sencha.com/touch/sencha-touch-2.1.1/sencha-touch-all.js

Please let me know why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use the sencha CMD to generate the project. That would provide you with a lot of commands including 'sencha app upgrade' which updates your app with a newer sdk.

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/guide/command

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/guide/command_app-section-upgrading-your-application